# lua interpreter, having to import file twice for full functionality

Tags: lua, interpreter, metatable

so i have a lua file analogous to this:

```
x = { __index = x}

constructor = function()
    local o = {}
    return setmetatable(o,x)
end

function x:print()
    print("hello world")
end
```

i type the following into the interpretr:

```
dofile "file.lua"
a = constructor()
a:print() --error attempt to call method 'print' (a nil value)

dofile "file.lua"
a = constructor()
a:print() -- hello world
```

the method works the second time i import the file but not the first. why is this?
I have tried changing the order (putting the constructor function last) and it was the same.

Answer (score 3):

The first time `x` is nil. It gets defined and then used the second time.

You need to write `x = {}; x.__index = x`.

Comment: @phatpat if this answer solved your problem, please accept it. This is how SO works, and help keep SO quality high. This is SO's way to say "thanks!".